# How to compute partial correlations with corrplot?

Tags: r, matrix, partial, pearson-correlation, r-corrplot

I usually use the following code to produce a nice correlation matrix - is there a **simple** way to control for variables with corrplot (i.e., to compute partial correlations instead of simple correlations)?

Thanks in advance!

```
library(corrplot)

# mat : is a matrix of data
# ... : further arguments to pass to the native R cor.test function
cor.mtest <- function(mat, ...) {
  mat <- as.matrix(mat)
  n <- ncol(mat)
  p.mat<- matrix(NA, n, n)
  diag(p.mat) <- 0
  for (i in 1:(n - 1)) {
    for (j in (i + 1):n) {
      tmp <- cor.test(mat[, i], mat[, j], ...)
      p.mat[i, j] <- p.mat[j, i] <- tmp$p.value
    }
  }
  colnames(p.mat) <- rownames(p.mat) <- colnames(mat)
  p.mat
}

#Select a subset of variables into a new df:

myvars <- c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14")
DataFactors <- Data[myvars]

M<-cor(DataFactors)

# matrix of the p-value of the correlation
p.mat <- cor.mtest(DataFactors )
head(p.mat[, 1:5])

col <- colorRampPalette(c("#BB4444", "#EE9988", "#FFFFFF", "#77AADD", "#4477AA"))
corrplot(M, method="color", col=col(200),  
         type="upper", 
         addCoef.col = "black", # Add coefficient of correlation
         tl.col="black", tl.srt=45, #Text label color and rotation
         # Combine with significance
         p.mat = p.mat, sig.level = 0.05, insig = "blank", 
         # hide correlation coefficient on the principal diagonal
         diag=FALSE 
)
```

Comment: You should be able to compute the matrices you need with `corr.test`, `partial.r' and `corr.p` in package `psych`.

Comment: I read about it but didn't understand how to implement it. How do I create the correlation matrix for 14 variables, while controlling for another variable?

Comment: You need to provide  a reproducible example of your data if you want a specific solution. That can be a sample of your data (e.g. 5 variables, 15 cases) or any of the data sets provided when you install R that are accessible to all R users. The `partial.r` function lets you specify variables for the correlation matrix and specify variable(s) that you want to control for. The `corr.p` function allows you to compute a matrix of p-values for partial correlations. You do not need the `cor.mtest` function.

Comment: @dcarlson
Thank you! I used partial.r and was able to compute the partial correlations.
I want to present only the first row of this matrix using corrplot, but for some reason it is not working.

```
corrplot(M_pr[,1:14],[1:14,1, drop=FALSE], cl.pos='n', method="color", col=col(200),  
         type="upper" 
         )
```

Comment: I'm don't think that `corrplot` will work with a piece of a correlation matrix. Contact the package maintainer.